# share a scope between views/controller

Tags: angularjs, algorithm

I have an issue that is more of algorithm than code.

let's explain what I want:

I have a tree view with elements that I can order. When I double click on one of these elements I want the page to swicth to a form, filled with the info of the clicked element. When I save the form, it goes back to the tree view, the element modified.

How I tried to do this ?

I have my main view, treeView, with its controller treeViewController. I have a factory, which loads the elements.

```
//treeViewController
$scope = factory.getelement()
//whatever else I need
```

I've tried to have another view "fullEdit" and I want it to share the scope, completely (it can also share the same controller it doesn't mater actually).
That's means when I modify $scope.element in "fullEdit" its modified in the tree.

Problem is, as the controller loads the scope, everytime I switch the view I reload the 
scope.

I've tried ui-router with nested states (I don't think that's the solution). Multiple-views is advised by many to get what I want, but I've tried it and all I get is both views on the same page, which is not what I want. Moreover it seems that these two views are still independent.

Also,using the global scope doesn't seem a good solution.

EDIT/ actually my issue is that when I change views the controllers are executed, thus the scope is reloaded from the back end. I don't want that, I want to share the $scope but not reload it every time I change the view !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myCtrlOne', function myCtrlOne($scope, reusableData) {
    $scope.service = reusableData
  })
  .controller('myCtrlTwo', function myCtrlOne($scope, reusableData) {
    $scope.service = reusableData
  })
  .service('reusableData', function() {
    return {
      message: 'initial msg'
    }
  })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrlOne">
    <input type="text" ng-model="service.message">
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrlTwo">
    <input type="text" ng-model="service.message">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you run this snippet (god I lvoe this function) you will see two inputs each inside different controller, they share data via service and as long as the page doesn't reload the service (which is simpleton - one instance per run) will keep your changes

Comment: this seems a good way to go. I just have to hide/unhide one of the div. It's what I intended to do originally simply with Jquery but it's better sharing the scope. thanks i'll try it tonight.

Comment: the service will share the data across the views as well, you can use separate controllers and then inject service and that's it

Comment: service, not factory ?

Comment: it can be factory as well, but I see service more suitable for this task

Comment: this doesn't work with different views... because every time the controller is executed it loads back the original state of message...

Comment: It clearly works, I've done this multiple times. Please share some code so I could tell what's wrong

Comment: with multiple views everytime you switch views $scope.service is reloaded to the value of "initial msg"

Comment: Have you even tried? http://plnkr.co/edit/pt2xwlYqvY3r840tHJ92?p=preview that's two-way data binding between controllers and multiple views

Comment: yes I had but there was something I did wrong I think. My service contained a function and I was doing $scope.service = reusableData.getData(). this function beeing an $http.get
For my own understand, a service is executed outside a controller ? even if never called ?